# No sound setting in settings panel manager

Tags: audio, settings

Sound settings is missed from settings panel.
I try launch it from a terminal with command **gnome-control-center**:

I already did install gnome-control-center:

```
#sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-control-center is already the newest version (1:3.18.2-1ubuntu6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
valeriy@valeriy-HP-ProBook-450-G5 ~ $
```

And when I launch the gnome-control-center sound from console, I have the next messages:

```
# gnome-control-center sound

** (gnome-control-center:11036): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ljc9eyj0jN: Connection refused

** (gnome-control-center:11036): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11036): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher language-selector (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11036): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher software-properties-gtk (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11036): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11036): WARNING **: Could not find settings panel "sound"`
```

- I get a gui window with settings, but no sound settings icon:

[image]